# Result Coming back from the Server is cutting off and throw not Valid JSON Exception

Tags: java, android, json, wcf

I am calling a wcf web service in android. All appear to work fine until I call a method that is returning quite a bit of data. It appears the result is being cut off and throwing not a valid json object. I check the result, and it return about 9089 characters. The bufferedreader and inputstreamreader have both return the same count with the same result. I try calling a different method that is returning about 2000 records, and it work without problems.

Here is the sample code where I am reading the result:

```
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
            InputStream stream1 =responseEntity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream1);
            reader.read(buffer);
            stream1.close();
            String sInvokeReturnValue = new String(buffer);
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to trust the content length here; what if you try and read until no data is available? Do you still get the error?

Comment: Yes, I do get the same error if I were to replace read until no data is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All appear to work fine until I call a method that is returning quite a bit of data. It appears the result is being cut off and throwing not a valid json object.

I suspect that your read is hitting a buffer limit and returning not as many bytes as you are expecting.  You should put your read in a loop to make sure you get all of the input.

What I would recommend is to use a `StringWriter` to read in your data.  For example:

```
// not much point on allocating a huge buffer here
char[] buffer = new char[4096];
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(responseEntity.getContent());
try {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    while (true) {
        int numRead = reader.read(buffer);
        if (numRead < 0) {
           break;
        }
        writer.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
    }
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
stream1.close();
String sInvokeReturnValue = writer.toString();
```